# Forcing dependency in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

Today our product broke because Play automatically updated to the last version of a library that breaks another one.

Is there a way to force a specific library in Play?

That is, we want that when we load a library

```
lazy val spring_aop = "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "4.1.7"
```

the 4.2.0 version is loaded and not the 4.1.7

I tried appending force() to the definition or using dependencyOverrides, but as I do a Play "update" command, I get the last version downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play doesn't update automatically anything. Application dependencies are defined in `build.sbt` and `plugins.sbt`.

In your case probably there is a confilct with subdependecies. One of libraries depends on version 4.1.7 and other one on 4.2.0. Sbt in this sitation aoumatically include newer package. To resolve it:

- diagnose with packages depends on `spring-aop`. This is good tool for it https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph
- exclude `spring-aop` from one of packages http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies

There is a risk that you brake functionalistes of other packages when you downgrade spring-aop